# Django file upload with Non-ASCII chars dropped

Tags: python, django, unicode

I am uploading a file to my Django model with unicode characters in the filename, however when the name is shown, they are dropped or changed to the closest ascii character. I checked the upload path function, and at this point it is still correctly encoded.

```
-> return u'proposal_documents/{0}/{1}'.format(instance.proposal.pk, filename)
(Pdb) x = u'proposal_documents/{0}/{1}'.format(instance.proposal.pk, filename)
(Pdb) x
u'proposal_documents/22872/\xa9\u02da\u2206\u222b\u02dau\u0308\u2122\xa2.png'
```

I also have checked the file's cleaned data, and the file is correctly represented there as well.

```
-> for file_ in pdform.cleaned_data['files']:
(Pdb) pdform.cleaned_data['files']
[<InMemoryUploadedFile: ©˚∆∫˚ü™¢.png (image/png)>]
```

However, inspecting the model, the non-ascii characters have been changed.

```
(Pdb) models.ProposalDocument.objects.order_by('-created_at')
<QuerySet [<ProposalDocument: u.png>, ...
```

this is reiterated in the model instance's file path

```
(Pdb) models.ProposalDocument.objects.order_by('-created_at').first().file.name
u'proposal_documents/22872/u.png'
```

Below is the model (with `import pdb; pdb.set_trace()` removed)

```
def proposal_doc_upload_path(instance, filename):
    return u'proposal_documents/{0}/{1}'.format(instance.proposal.pk, filename)


class ProposalDocument(models.Model):
    proposal = models.ForeignKey(Proposal, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='documents')
    file = models.FileField(upload_to=proposal_doc_upload_path, max_length=500, blank=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(Employee, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.file.name.rsplit('/')[-1].encode('utf-8')
```

How do I alter my code so that unicode characters are kept unchanged?
I am using Django 1.10 and Python 2.7

Comment: Were you able to fix it?

Comment: I was never able to fix it; it turned out to be an internal Django issue.

Comment: I saw my table collation was wrong, after changing it to utf8_unicode_ci it worked fine.